# SQL injection in SP_EXECUTESQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-injection, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which gets a XML as input parameter. In this XML is defined - what stored procedure with which parameters values should be executed. And according to that the stored procedure execute the wanted one using dynamic SQL with `sp_executesql`.

The problem is that the values of the parameters are vulnerable to SQL injection.

I have tried using typed parameters like that:

```sql
EXEC sys.sp_executesql 
  @stmt = @sql, 
  @params = N'@Username SYSNAME, @HireDate DATE',
  @UserName = @Username, @HireDate = @HireDate;
```

But it doesn't really work in my case, because I don't know what procedure with what parameters will be executed. The number of parameters may vary and some of them are optional / have default values etc. All I can get is the names of the parameters as string :(

After some parsing of the input XML the SQL Query is build and executed like that

```sql
declare @params nvarchar(max);
    select @params = coalesce(@params + N', ', N' ') + r.attrName + N' = ' + iif(p.isNumericType = 1, r.Value, '''' + r.Value /*cast(r.Value as nvarchar(max))*/ + '''') --+ r.Value
    from dbo.#ruleConfig r
        left join @spParams p on p.paramName = r.attrName -- datatype of a parameter from information_schema.parameters 

    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = (select @procName + isnull(@params, N''));

    exec dbo.sp_executesql @sql
```

The value of @sql can look something like that:

```
'core.GetUser @LogonName = 'myDomain\myLogon''
```

But also can look like that:

```
'core.GetUser @fullLogonName = 'myDomain\myLogon;'WAITFOR DELAY '0:0:20';--'' and that's the problem.
```

Comment: `In this XML is defined - what store procedure with which parameters values should be executed.` why? Why have the *database* parse this string instead of having the client properly call the stored procedure? That's the root of the problem, not `sp_executesql`

Comment: That string, whether it can be parsed as XML or not, is itself vulnerable to SQL injection and conversion errors. It's also hundreds of times larger than a proper call to the database using ADO.NET, ODBC or whatever protocol your language uses.

Comment: *"But it doesn't really work in my case, because I don't know what procedure with what parameters will be executed."* Then you could build a dynamic dynamic statement (not ideal, but I've seen it), or pass all the parameters regardless if they'll be used inside the dynamic statement or not. `EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT 1 AS one;',N'@i int', @i = @i;` won't error, even though `@i` is never used in the "dynamic" query. We don't have any information here, really, to be able to give a full answer for this though.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to make this secure. If you can't trust your user, then don't do it. Parse your XML to individual local variables and use only those local variables in regular database statements.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, if you have any functionality that requires you to send *dynamic* SQL stored procedures execution commands, you have a big problem with your design as with a strict tightly-coupled design, each API call will be mapped to a single stored procedure.

If you still wish to stick with the current design, than you have to create a list of known stored procedures and their values. You cannot just accept the fact that you "don't know what procedure with what parameters will be executed" because than your publish an SQL Injection functionality by-design.

You need to create an enum of the known stored procedures (for example 1 = proc1, 2 = proc2 etc.) and perform a regular-expression-based input validation to their parameters.

In the example you just gave, if you want "myDomain\myLogon" to be accepted and "myDomain\myLogon;'WAITFOR DELAY '0:0:20';--" to be rejected, you can for example use a regular expression that looks like this:

```
^([A-Za-z\\])*$
```

You can test it in the [regexr](https://regexr.com/) website.
You'll have to create an input validation regex for each field type - for example names, usernames, emails etc. Basically it's pretty similar to just creating a separate API for each procedure call, with proper input validation.